# model.evaluate() loss metric calculation in Bayesian Neural Net

Tags: tensorflow, keras, metrics, bayesian-networks, bayesian-deep-learning

I am currently trying to set up a Bayesian Neural Net. Hereby, I came across a strange thing.
When compiling my model with the metric keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError() and then letting model.evaluate() run, the function gives me the RMSE.
However, when I manually calculate the RMSE, the result is way different and indeed better (and more reasonable comparing to an ANN).

Does anyone of you have an idea, why the results differ and how is model.evaluate() calculating the RMSE in a probabilistic Neural Net?

Thanks for you help!!

```py
def create_probabilistic_bnn_model(input_dim, hidden_units, kl_weight):
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=input_dim)
    features = layers.BatchNormalization()(inputs)
    features = features

    # Create hidden layers with weight uncertainty using the DenseVariational layer.
    for units in hidden_units:
        features = tfp.layers.DenseVariational(
            units=units,
            make_prior_fn=prior,
            make_posterior_fn=posterior,
            kl_weight=kl_weight,
            activation="sigmoid",
        )(features)
        #features = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(features, training=True)
        # if last_output is not None:
        #     features += last_output  # residual layer
        # last_output = features

    # Create a probabilistic output (Normal distribution), and use the `Dense` layer
    # to produce the parameters of the distribution.
    # We set units=2 to learn both the mean and the variance of the Normal distribution.
    distribution_params = layers.Dense(units=2)(features)

    outputs = tfp.layers.IndependentNormal(1)(distribution_params)

    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model


def negative_loglikelihood(targets, estimated_distribution):
    return -estimated_distribution.log_prob(targets)


for n in [8]:  # [8, 16, 24]
    for layer in [[n, n]]:  # [[n, n], [n, n, n], [n, n, n, n]]
        bnn_model_probabilistic = create_probabilistic_bnn_model(
            data_size, layer, 1 / len(train_dataloader.dataset)
        )

        bnn_model_probabilistic.compile(
            optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01),
            loss=negative_loglikelihood,
            metrics=[keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()],
        )

        callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
            monitor="loss", patience=PATIENCE, verbose=1
        )
        # Define the learning rate scheduler callback
        lr_callback = LearningRateScheduler(lr_scheduler, verbose=0)

        print("Start training the model...")
        history = bnn_model_probabilistic.fit(
            x=feature_train, y=label_train, epochs=EPOCHS, callbacks=            
        [callback, lr_callback],
        validation_data=[feature_val, label_val]
        )
        print("Model training finished.")
        
        print()

        bnn_model_probabilistic_history = history

print(bnn_model_probabilistic.summary())
print(bnn_model_probabilistic.metrics_names)

# list all data in history
print(history.history.keys())

_, rmse_train_bnn = bnn_model_probabilistic.evaluate(x=feature_train,     
    y=label_train, verbose=0)
_, rmse_test_bnn = bnn_model_probabilistic.evaluate(x=feature_test, 
    y=label_test, verbose=0) 


#RMSE Test
BNN_residual_test = label_test - BNN_result_dataframe_test['mean']
sq_BNN_residual_test = BNN_residual_test**2
BNN_MSE_test = np.mean(sq_BNN_residual_test)
rmse_test_bnn = np.sqrt(BNN_MSE_test)
```

Comment: It's very likely that your implementation may not be appropriate, but we can't help you out without the code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I edited the post and pasted my code.

Comment: Can you send us how you have calculated the RMSE yourself?

Comment: Of course! So I saved the results from the model into a dataframe as the BNN is calculating a distribution. I took the mean of this distribution as the point estimation.

I appended the provided code above.

Comment: I'm sorry. I wasn't able to find a solution. Have you got any progress by this time?

Comment: No worries, but thank you for your effort! I myself haven't found a solution yet, but I will keep you updated in case I got one.